# Get Xmin,Xmax,Ymin,Ymax from polygon in Python

Tags: python, polygon

I have a polygon. I want a CSV file that contains the xmin, xmax, ymin,ymax extent from the polygon in Python. What are the ways I can do it?

Comment: What have you tried? Where is this polygon? Drawn on a piece of paper or stored in a secure server? Which GIS do you intend to use to extract the extent?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

#### Use numpy and fiona:

```
import numpy as np
import fiona as fio

# Open geometry

shapefile = fio.open(inputpath) # or geojson

shapefile.bounds

# Extract values

minx = shapefile.bounds[0]
miny = shapefile.bounds[1]
maxx = shapefile.bounds[2]
maxy = shapefile.bounds[3]

# Print values

print('minx =', minx)
print('miny =', miny)
print('maxx =', maxx)
print('maxy =', maxy)


# Save with numpy to.csv

rows = [ ['minx', minx], 
         ['miny', miny], 
         ['maxx', maxx], 
         ['maxy', maxy]]

np.savetxt(fname = outputpath,
           X   = rows,
           fmt = '% s',
           delimiter = ', ',
           newline   = '\n')
```

[image]